# nodejs Angular error in module app not available

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Module 'ConatactsApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.  `var ContactsApp= angular.module('ContactsApp', [])
.run(function ($rootScope){
    $rootScope.message = "Hello angular";
});`

Comment: More information is necessary.  Is this the *exact* error you are receiving or is `'ConatactsApp'` a mistype in your question body? What file is this code in? is the file loaded into your HTML scripts?  Is the file accessible?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='ConatactsApp'>
<head>
 <title>Contacts</title>
 <base href="/"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="page-header">
  <h1> Contacts: {{message}} </h1>
 </div>
</div>
<script src='jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='src/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: don't add code in comments, it is impossible to read and doesn't help clarify your question.  edit the question body instead.

Comment: this is the link of angular error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ConatactsApp

Comment: That being said, this does indeed prove that the typo is in your code, not in the question body.  fix `html ng-app='ConatactsApp'`.

Comment: sorry sir i am first time using stack overflow so i make mistaks

Comment: how can i fix this `html ng-app='ConatactsApp'

Comment: try `ContactsApp` instead of `ConatactsApp`.  remove the extra `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the html ng-app name is ConatactsApp or something else...  if not ...  change to ConatactsApp